# MongoDB Query to Update Only The First Array Value That Matches Criteria

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need some help writing a Mongo query that would update only one the first instance in an array where the criteria is matched.

I am not the best explaining what I need in words, so I will put sample data and query to hopefully explain what I am looking for better.

Assuming I have data that looks like the following:

```
{
    "num": "q22",
    "top": [
        {
            "mid": { "value": "222" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "222" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "333" }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "num": "q33",
    "top": [
        {
            "mid": { "value": "222" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "999" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "111" }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would need add a new attribute to the "top" array called "new" and set it to 45 only in the first instance of the top array where num is "q22" and mid.value is "222" while leaving the other instance .

So at the end of the update, I would need the sample data above to look like:

```
{
    "num": "q22",
    "top": [
        {
            "mid": { "value": "222" },
            "new": 45
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "222" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "333" }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "num": "q33",
    "top": [
        {
            "mid": { "value": "222" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "999" }
        },
        {
            "mid": { "value": "111" }
        }
    ]
}
```

This query will ultimately be constructed programmatically and run across a large list of data, so the ordering of the "top" array cannot be assumed.

My initial query I started with looked something like:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "num": "q22" },
    { $set: { "top.$[elem].new": 45 } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.mid.value": "222" } ] }
)
```

But this will create the new value on both of the "top" array objects with mid.value as "222" rather than just on the first one. I have been struggling with trying to modify this to update only the first arrayFilter match and ignore the rest.

Hope I explained well enough and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [positional operator, `$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "num": "q22",
  "top.mid.value": "222"
},
{
  $set: {
    "top.$.new": 45
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hsEHJ0SWAh6)